# How can I disable the colors dialog for Texmate?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I often edit a webpage in HTML and then switch to Chrome to preview it. In chrome to activate the web inspector you can use `Command+Shift+C` but if you're in `Textmate` that will pull up the colors dialog:

[image]

How can I prevent this dialog from being activated with `Command+Shift+C` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply prevent Command+Shift+C shortcut in TextMate, then you can use BetterTouchTool for this. BTT is primarily used for creating custom touchpad and magic mouse gestures, but it handles keystrokes as well. I recommend to try this app not only for blocking the Command+Shift+C shortcut.

Try:
BTT Preferences – add TextMate to the left panel – keyboard tab – add Command+Shift+C and set No action to it.

Comment: I tested this solution and I noticed that while BTT supports app-specific gestures, keystrokes are only global.

Comment: Thanks, I like BTT a lot. I ended up using FastScripts to set an app-specific keyboard shortcut as you mentioned.